# Typeorm many-to-many select rows with no relationship

Tags: mysql, nestjs, typeorm

I have two tables, that have many to many relationship.

```js
@Entity()
export class DiscountPlan {
  //...other columns

  @ManyToMany(() => CustomerGroup, (group) => group.discountPlans)
  @JoinTable()
  groups: CustomerGroup[];
}
```

```js
@Entity()
export class CustomerGroup {
  //...other columns

  @ManyToMany(() => DiscountPlan, (plan) => plan.groups)
  discountPlans: DiscountPlan[];
}
```

now I need to get discount plans that either have no relations(no groups) or has relation with given groupId(it comes from customer entity).

I have to do it with `queryBuilder`.

thanks.

Comment: What have you tried? What is not working? In general it sounds like a simple LEFT JOIN and WHERE clause where you check for "groupId = something OR groupId IS NULL"

Comment: @enak
I made it work with using the junction table name directly(which I was trying to avoid).

```const plansWithGroupQuery = this.createQueryBuilder().subQuery().select('dtg.discountPlanId').from('discount_plan_groups_customer_group', 'dtg').groupBy('dtg.discountPlanId')```
```this.createQueryBuilder('dp').select('dp').where(...).leftJoin('dp.groups', 'g').andWhere(new Brackets((qb) => { qb.where(`dp.id NOT IN (${plansWithGroupQuery.getQuery()})`);
qb.orWhere(`g.id = "${groupId}"`);}),)```